# Matlab figure: Replace xaxis with custom labels

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, figure

I have a figure and would like to replace the x axis of the plot to a custom one. So now there are the values from 0 to 300 on the x axis, but I need it to show the values from 1 to 10 in a equal distance on the whole width of the figure. How do I do that?

Here are the figure and the code, if this helps:

[image: link to imgage]

```
sun = dataset.sun
%time = dataset.time

figure
plot(sun)
```

So far I tried some options for manipulating the existing x axis, but not really succesfull so far.

Comment: Did you try plotting against the x values? `plot(time, sun)`

Comment: Yes, this would lead to another xaxis, but I just would like to have the values of 1 up to 10 on the axis, although the datapoints for the signal are much more broader.

Comment: Are [`xlim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) or [`xticks`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html) what you want?

Comment: Then set `time = linspace(0,10,length(sun))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to explicitly set `time` like the comments,
You can use axis() to modify the axis bounds. https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html

```
axis([0 10 0 inf]) % array follows [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
```